# Get exact match of taxonomy terms, not a partial match

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

I have set up a loop to display content for an EXACT match of two taxonomy terms.  However, the code I have used is including results with partial matches.  How do I adjust the IF statement so it only shows the exact matches?

For a little context I should only get results when the age group is exactly 1st and 2nd grade.  Not those that include 1st and 2nd grades along with other grades.

Here is the code I have been using:

```php
<div class="sc-age-group">
    <?php 
    $agegroup = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'camper_grade');
    if ($agegroup) {
        foreach ($agegroup as $group) {
            if ($group->name == "1st Grade" && "2nd Grade") { ?>
                <div class="sc-age-group_1-2">Grades 1 - 2</div> <?php ;
            }

        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The logical operator is most likely failing because `&& "2nd Grade"` doesn't mean that the `$group->name` also equals that. You need to have both values checked `if ($group->name == "1st Grade" &&  $group->name == "2nd Grade")`. But you're also going to run into issues because you are checking each age group independently in the `foreach` - I don't think your condition will ever be met. What do you taxonomy terms look like?

Comment: Disinfor, my tax terms are preschhol, kindergarten, 1st grade, 2nd grade, 3rd grade etc.  In general how can you serch tax terms that are an exact match?

Comment: Oh and fyi, i do get results already for both terms being checked....however it also includes programs that have kidergarten, 1st grade, and 2nd grade...but i only want results to show exact match not partial match

Comment: Like @disinfor says the syntax of your statement is wrong. Also the statement will probably never be met. For it to be true the group name needs to be "1st Grade" and "2nd Grade" at the same time. That could never be true. Maybe you are looking for the `||` (or) operator

Comment: @jrswgtr - ok so if the syntax is wrong, what's the correct method?  I am not looking for ````||````. My taxonomy has multiple grades and when one program is just for 1st and 2nd grade I would like that to display.  Any ideas?

Comment: You basically need to get both 1st and 2nd grade or whatever, combine them into another variable and use that for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten everything to work in a big part to the code from @jrswgtr.  Since my original code was slightly different than the set up from @jrswgtr, here is my final code in case it helps anyone else.

```
<?php 
  $agegroup = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'camper_grade');
    if ($agegroup) {
      foreach ($agegroup as $group) {
        if ($group->name == '1st Grade' && '2nd Grade' && count($agegroup) == 2) { ?>
            <div class="sc-age-group_1-2">Grades 1 - 2</div> <?php ;
        }       
      }
  }         
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To know if both groups are in your array of terms you will have to loop through all of them and check their name. If they match you save them in a different array. Every iteration you count the array to check if both groups are present. Then you can print the HTML and break the loop.

```
<div class="sc-age-group">
    <?php $agegroup = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'camper_grade') ?>
    <?php $groups = []; ?>

    <?php foreach ($agegroup as $group): ?>
        <?php if ($group->name === "1st Grade" || $group->name === "2nd Grade"): ?>
            <?php $groups[] = $group; ?>
            <?php if (count($groups) === 2): ?>
                <div class="sc-age-group_1-2">Grades 1 - 2</div>
                <?php break; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

To take away @disinfor's concern about the possibility of two terms with the same name (not likely but surely possible), I made a second solution. It will first loop through all terms and after that check if both `1st Grade` and `2nd Grade` are present.

```
<?php $agegroup = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'camper_grade') ?>
<?php $groupNames = []; ?>
<?php foreach ($agegroup as $group): ?>
    <?php $groupNames[] = $group->name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="sc-age-group">
    <?php if (in_array('1st Grade', $groupNames) && in_array('2nd Grade', $groupNames)): ?>
        <div class="sc-age-group_1-2">Grades 1 - 2</div>         
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Another addition:
I suggest you use the `slug` of the term instead of the `name`. The `slug` must be unique for each term, contrary to the `name`.

Given that the slug for `1st Grade` is `1st-grade` and the slug for `2nd Grade` is `2nd-grade`:

```
<?php $agegroup = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'camper_grade') ?>
<?php $groupSlugs = []; ?>
<?php foreach ($agegroup as $group): ?>
    <?php $groupSlugs[] = $group->slug; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="sc-age-group">
    <?php if (in_array('1st-grade', $groupSlugs) && in_array('2nd-grade', $groupSlugs) && count($groupSlugs) < 3): ?>
        <div class="sc-age-group_1-2">Grades 1 - 2</div>         
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The second check should be `2nd Grade`. You also don't need the `break` since the if condition will be met, the break will automatically happen.

Comment: @disinfor You're right about the 2nd grade thing, corrected ;-). However, I don't see how the break will automatically happen. I'm pretty sure if you won't break, the loop will continue until all terms are iterated. Not a problem, but just a waste of resources since you already got all the info you need. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `if` statements will break as soon as the condition is met. In your case, once the count is equal to 2. If you look at how the code is working, you have the `foreach` which will iterate over the initial array for each item, testing that the two conditions in the next `if` statement are met - however, it still will look at the entire initial array - and then will eventually get to your final `if` statement. A better way to do this might be to assign the array for the `$groups` and then output it after the `foreach`. Either way, what you have works.

Comment: For all I know, `break;` in this case, will stop the loop when the condition in the second if-statement (the array `$group` contains two entries) is met. Preventing unneeded iterations. If you check and output after the `foreach` it will need to loop through all entries first, wasting resources.

Comment: in the case of `['1st grade', '2nd grade', '3rd grade', '4th grade']` the loop will break after the first 2 iterations. in the case of `['1st grade', '3rd grade', '4th grade', '2nd grade']` it will indeed need to iterate the whole array.

Comment: The issue is if there is more than one `1st grade` in the original array (there shouldn't be). Also, if I'm not mistaken, you're only breaking out of that inner `if`, so the outer `if` and `foreach` will still run anyway. I don't think resource allocation is a factor here, since, I'm assuming, the initial array is so small that any performance issues will be negligible.

Comment: I guess you're right about that possible second entry. I made another solution to fix that issue ;-)

Comment: I think that second solution is not only cleaner, but also safer. Upvoted!

Comment: I think it's also better to use the slug instead of the name because it's unique for every term. Added another example ;-)

Comment: @jswgtr, I am sorry to say that this process provides the same results as my original code.  I think the issue still remains that programs that have Kindergarten, 1st grade, and 2nd grade are still displaying.  I don't see where this excludes programs that are not an exact match of grades 1 and 2 only.  Excluding programs that are K-2 or K-6.  Any ideas?

Comment: @lisrael you're right, I misread a part of your question. I updated my third example with an extra clause in the if statement. Should work now!

Comment: @jrswgtr - That did it!  It worked by adding the `count();` to my existing code.  I will write my official solution as an answer since it's slightly different than your set up.